# Nanosecond-precision timestamp prefixes with boost::log

Tags: c++, boost-log

Currently I use `boost::log` to log to the console with:

```
boost::log::add_console_log(std::clog, keywords::format = "%TimeStamp% %Message%");
```

How can I change the printed timestamps to have nanosecond precision?

Assume that my timing system can report nanoseconds reliably.

Comment: First make sure your timing system can report nanoseconds reliably. Usually this level of precision requires specialized hardware. Not much sense investing a bunch of time into figuring out how to write nanoseconds if you find out later that you can't deliver nanoseconds.

Comment: @user4581301 Fixed my post to clarify the assumption.

Comment: Find the `boost` time object.  Figure out how `boost` determines the timestamp.  This function or object needs to be able to fetch the time with nanosecond precision.  Also, examine the `boost` library code to see how the time (duration) is formatted.  Does it allow nanoseconds?

Comment: boost log allows you to specify formatters to change how it handles stuff like the timestamp. Never used one, though.